# MudBlazor's Autocomplete is not working even if the component is filled with data

Tags: mudblazor

Whenever I type the string for the MudBlazor's Autocomplete, the component does not give me the result. I can get all the data inside the Autocomplete Component, but cannot search for it.

**razor.cs**

```
private PropertyTransactionType _sPropertyTransactionType;
        private PropertyTransactionType SPropertyTransactionType
        {
            get => _sPropertyTransactionType;
            set
            {
                _sPropertyTransactionType = value;
            }
        }
 private async Task<IEnumerable<PropertyTransactionType>> Search(string value)
        {
            return PropertyTransactionTypes;
        }
```

**razor**

```
<MudAutocomplete T="ascor_pmis.Shared.Entities.Properties.Parameters.PropertyTransactionType" 
                                                     Label="Transaction Type" 
                                                     @bind-Value="SPropertyTransactionType"
                                                     SearchFunc="@Search"
                                                     ToStringFunc="@(e=> e==null?null : $"{e.TransactionType} [{e.Debit_Credit}]")" />
```

Comment: `SPropertyTransactionType` looks odd. Shouldn't that be `@PropertyTransactionType`?

Comment: @BartKiers , sorry about that Sir, they have the same data type sir. Please see my edit.. Thank you.

Comment: The autocomplete examples on the site of MudBlazor work just fine (see: https://mudblazor.com/components/autocomplete#api), could you make a small demo that shows the problem: https://try.mudblazor.com/ ?

Comment: [source code line] (https://github.dev/MudBlazor/MudBlazor/blob/dev/src/MudBlazor/Components/Autocomplete/MudAutocomplete.razor.cs#L127-L128) notice the Search method return type! I used Task.FromResult()